# CamelCase регулярка

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст в формате:

Люблю_грозу в_начале_Мая, "Когда весенний_первый_Гром", 
как бы Резвяся_и Играя, Грохочет в_небе_голубом.

Должно стать:

ЛюблюГрозу вНачалеМая, "Когда весенний_первый_Гром",
как бы РезвясяИ Играя, Грохочет вНебеГолубом.

Поясню, нужно убрать все подчеркивания, кроме тех что в кавычках, там все должно быть без изменений. С великой подачи мастера регулярных выражений (sercxjo) мы смогли разобраться с подчеркиванием (`"_(?=([^\"]*[^\\\\])(\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\\\.)*\"[^\"]*)*$)"`), но теперь нам надо написать регулярку которая подымает регистр букв стоящих после подчеркивания, но так же не трогает текст в кавычках.

Comment: И где же то выражение, которое работает без кавычек?

Comment: "_(?=([^\"]*[^\\\\])(\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"[^\"]*)*$)"

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку - а стоит ли извращаться с регулярками, если удобнее и читаемее было бы написать алгоритм? Навскидку решение не приходит регуляркой, а если напишите - в этом чёрт не разберётся потом.

Comment: Александр, я вижу это как: Проходим методом replaceAll - меняем все буквы нижнего регистра на верхний, стоящие после подчеркивания. А потом пробегаемся этим же методом и удаляем все подчеркивания. Вы просто ответьте - возможно ли написать регулярку меняющие регистр ?

Comment: ReplaceAll() меняет все вхождения подстроки в строке на новую подстроку, в вашем же случае подстрока на замену не одна, а несколько и этот метод не применим.

Comment: Я и спрашиваю, первый replaceAll с помощью регулярки меняет регистр всех букв после подчеркивания за исключением тех что в кавычках, а второй replaceAll меняет все подчеркивания на ничего ) Вторую часть я сделал

Comment: Вы снова не поняли, регулярки не меняют строки, они ищут подстроки в строках, в соответствии с вашими правилами. ReplaceAll(<то что надо заменить>, <на что меняем>). Регулярка вам вернула <то что надо заменить> (_г, _н, _м, _и, _н), как определить <на что меняем> здесь значение не постоянное?

Comment: Я у вас как у спецов и спрашиваю - возможно ли собрать регулярное выражение, которое может "менять_все_буквы_нижнего_регистра_на_верхний_если_буква_стоит_после_подчеркивания_но_не_трогать_то_что_в_ковыяках"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен класс `Matcher`, код примерно следующий:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            String regex = "_[а-яА-ЯёЁъЪ](?=([^\"]*[^\\\\])(\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"[^\"]*)*$)";
            String str = "Люблю_грозу в_начале_Мая, \"Когда весенний_первый_Гром\", как бы Резвяся_и Играя, Грохочет в_небе_голубом.";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

            while (matcher.find()){
                String s = str.substring(matcher.end()-1,matcher.end()).toUpperCase();
                str = str.replace(str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()),s);
                matcher.reset(str);
            }

            System.out.println(str);
   }
```

Единственное, я забыл как получить сразу совпадения по регулярке, поэтому код можно улучшить.

Comment: Спасибо, с вашего позволения поковыряю ваш код ) Я читал с файла и записывал результат в файл, а между ними писал вот это - String everything = read("C:\\a.java").replaceAll("_(?=([^\"]*[^\\\\])(\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"[^\"]*)*$)", "");

Comment: Алексей, код хороший, рабочий. Где то раз дал осечку, но я не смог ее поймать ) Спасибо !

Comment: Вообще, в Java конструкции типа `([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*` надо развертывать ("unroll-the-loop"), иначе при обработке длинных строк может выскочить stack overflow. Совпадение по регулярке - `matcher.group(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Как решить вашу задачу, используя исключительно средства работы с регулярными выражениями - я не знаю, но можно попробовать написать аналог метода `Matcher.replaceAll` например вот так:

```
 String myReplaceAll(String pattern, String text, String replacement) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int length = 0; m.find(); length = sb.length()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            if(length > 0) {
                sb.setCharAt(length, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(length)));
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Можно сделать то же без явного использования классов для работы с регулярными выражениями:

```
String myReplaceAll(String symbol, String text, String replacement) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String textChunk : text.split(symbol)) {
            int prevLength = sb.length();
            sb.append(textChunk);
            if(prevLength > 0)
            sb.setCharAt(prevLength,
                    Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(prevLength)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Или, как писали в комментариях, написать реализацию без регулярки, это особенно актуально, если вы будете искать не шаблоны в строка, а только отдельные символы. Для начала могу предложить что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
String myReplaceAll(char patternSymbol,
                                     char startSkippingSymbol,
                                     char stopSkippingSymbol,
                                     String text, String replacement) {
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        char[] resultString = new char[chars.length];
        boolean upperNext = false, stopSearching = false;
        for (int index = 0, newIndex = 0; index < chars.length; index++) {
            char symbol = chars[index];
            stopSearching = startSkippingSymbol == symbol ?
          (stopSearching ? false : true) : stopSearching;
            if(!stopSearching) {
                if (upperNext) {
                    symbol = Character.toUpperCase(symbol);
                    upperNext = false;
                }
                if (patternSymbol == symbol) {
                    upperNext = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            resultString[newIndex++]=symbol;
        }
        return new String(resultString);
    }
```

Comment: Валентин спасибо ! До вашего решения я свято верил в регулярки, оказывается зря !